# Batch file to find the shared folder and remove the sharing

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

```
@echo off
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET HOSTNAME=%%i

for /F %%a IN ('wmic /node:"%HOSTNAME%" share get path') DO (
IF "%%a"=="C:\windows" (
    echo "Cannot remove ADMIN shared Drive" %%a
) ELSE (
    NET SHARE %%a /DELETE
)

)

endlocal
```

I have written this script which runs as a windows scheduler. The script checks for the shared folder and removes the shared folder. The problem I am facing is when I run this alone

```
wmic /node:"%HOSTNAME%" share get path
```

I get:

```
Path
C:\windows
C:\
E:\
E:\someFolder
```

But when I run the script it removes only E:\ and E:\someFolder and not C:.
I have written condition not to remove the C:\windows but why does it skips C:.
Please help.

**UPDATE**
Actually I just saw its not deleting the share of any of the C:/ drive folders? Is  it a permission issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give a share example `odds and ends` with spaces in both share name and resource path:

```
==> net share | findstr /I "Resource --- odds \$"
Share name   Resource                        Remark
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ADMIN$       C:\Windows                      Remote Admin
C$           C:\                             Default share
D$           D:\                             Default share
IPC$                                         Remote IPC
print$       C:\Windows\system32\spool\drivers
odds and ends
             D:\bat\odds and ends

==>
```

The following script shows some mistakes in your script (explained mostly in comments and `ECHO`s). See also [Dave Benham's *`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET HOSTNAME=%%i

set "_narrow="                         your setting - get all 
set "_narrow=^| find /I "odds""        setting to narrow output - delete this line

echo(
echo --- ORIGINAL APPROACH: does not respect spaces in path ---
for /F %%a IN ('wmic /node:"%HOSTNAME%" share get path %_narrow%') DO echo [%%~a]

echo(
echo --- UPDATED: respects spaces in path but does not respect wmic behaviour ---
for /F "delims=" %%a IN ('wmic /node:"%HOSTNAME%" share get path %_narrow%') DO (
    echo [%%~a])

echo(
echo --- UPDATED: DBenham's solution preserves unwanted trailing spaces ---
for /F "delims=" %%a IN ('wmic /node:"%HOSTNAME%" share get path %_narrow%') DO (
  for /F "delims=" %%A in ("%%~a") do echo [%%~A]
)

echo(
echo --- WORKING SCRIPT ---
for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a IN ('
  wmic /node:"%HOSTNAME%" share get path /value %_narrow%
') do for /F "delims=" %%A in ("%%~b") do (
    IF /I "%%~A"=="C:\windows" (
        echo "Cannot remove ADMIN shared Drive" [%%A]
    ) ELSE (
        rem next NET SHARE command is merely ECHOed for debugging purposes 
        ECHO NET SHARE "%%~A" /DELETE
    )
)
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\42617143.bat

--- ORIGINAL APPROACH: does not respect spaces in path ---
[D:\bat\odds]

--- UPDATED: respects spaces in path but does not respect wmic behaviour ---
]D:\bat\odds and ends

--- UPDATED: DBenham's solution preserves unwanted trailing spaces ---
[D:\bat\odds and ends                 ]

--- WORKING SCRIPT ---
NET SHARE "D:\bat\odds and ends" /DELETE

==>
```

**Answer**. However, `NET` command **requires elevation** to perform some operations successfully:

```
==> NET SHARE "D:\bat\odds and ends" /DELETE
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.


==>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes this works, but even this, after making some more changes `FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET HOSTNAME=%%i FOR /F %%a IN ('wmic /node:"%HOSTNAME%" share get name') DO ( echo %%a  NET SHARE %%a /Y /DELETE
) endlocal` if I keep it in C:/ and run with windows scheduler with highest admin privilege.

Comment: Yes, getting `name` instead of `path` seems to be a good idea however keep using double quotes (to be on the safe side): `NET SHARE "%%~a" /Y /DELETE`